# Watson Speech To Text service works faster for which type of audio file?

Tags: audio, ibm-cloud, speech-to-text, watson

I have tried the Watson Speech to Text API for MP3 as well as WAV files. As per my observation, the same length of audio takes less time if its given in MP3 format as compared to WAV. 10 consecutive API calls with different audios took on an average 8.7 seconds for MP3 files. On the other hand the same input in WAV format took average 11.1 seconds. Does the service response time depend on the file type? Which file type is recommended to use to obtain the results faster?

Comment: How are you measuring? Is this after the upload or including network time?

Comment: Including network time. May we can consider 2-3 seconds less considering network performance. In any case, MP3 works faster than WAV. So want to know if the performance is affected by file type.

Comment: I am asking because mp3 files typically are smaller than wav. Have you checked how much data is transferred in the two cases?

Comment: Yes right. I have tried this with same length audios but mp3 file size was less as compared to wav.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different encoding formats have different bitrates. mp3 and opus are lossy compression formats (although suitable for speech recognition when bitrates are not too low) so they offer the lowest bitrates. If you need to push less bytes over the network that is typically better for latency, so depending on your network speed you can see shorter processing times when using encoding with lower bitrates.

However, regarding the actual speech recognition process (ignoring the data transfer over the network) all encodings are equally fast since before the recognition starts all the audio is uncompressed, if necessary, and converted to the sampling rate of the target model (broadband or narrowband).

Comment: Thank you so much. I think that answers my question. It totally depends on the requirement. If low latency is desired then lossy encoding format can be used. If accuracy is of utmost importance and some latency is acceptable, then lossless encoding formats must be used.

Comment: Yeah exactly, note however that if you use an acceptable bitrate, lossy formats such as opus wont degrade accuracy in a measurable way. With opus you can get the best of both worlds, best latency and no loss in accuracy. The key is to pick the right bitrate: this is a good list with values you can start with: https://wiki.xiph.org/Opus_Recommended_Settings  . This is also another interesting resource: http://opus-codec.org/comparison/

Comment: Thank you so much for the inputs!